# How to allow null in all column in django model with postgres?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-views

I want to allow all columns within my model to be nullable, when I try to insert data I get the following error.

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Here is my model code:

```
class Edu_Expense(models.Model):
    uin = models.ForeignKey(Claim)
    child_id = models.ForeignKey(Child_Info)
    edu_receipt = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True,blank=True)
    edu_fees = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    edu_date = models.DateField(default=None,null=True,blank=True)
    entry_receipt = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True,blank=True)
    entry_fees = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    entry_date = models.DateField(default=None,null=True,blank=True)
    lab_receipt = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True,blank=True)
    lab_fees = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    lab_date = models.DateField(default=None,null=True,blank=True)
    other_receipt = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True,blank=True)
    other_fees = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    other_date = models.DateField(default=None,null=True,blank=True)
    prac_receipt = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True,blank=True)
    prac_fees = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    prac_date = models.DateField(default=None,null=True,blank=True)
    instru_receipt = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True,blank=True)
    instru_fees = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    instru_date = models.DateField(default=None,null=True,blank=    True)
    lib_receipt = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True,blank=True)
    lib_fees = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    lib_date = models.DateField(default=None,null=True,blank=True)
    sport_receipt = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True,blank=True)
    sport_fees = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    sport_date = models.DateField(default=None,null=True,blank=True)
    coedu_receipt = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True,blank=True)
    coedu_fees = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    coedu_date = models.DateField(default=None,null=True,blank=True)
    board_receipt = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True,blank=True)
    board_fees = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    board_date = models.DateField(default=None,null=True,blank=True)
    books_receipt = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True,blank=True)
    books_fees = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    books_date = models.DateField(default=None,null=True,blank=True)
    notebook_receipt = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True,blank=True)
    notebook_fees = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    notebook_date = models.DateField(default=None,null=True,blank=True)
    uniform_receipt = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True,blank=True)
    uniform_fees = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    uniform_date = models.DateField(default=None,null=True,blank=True)
    shoes_receipt = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True,blank=True)
    shoes_fees = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    shoes_date = models.DateField(default=None,null=True,blank=True)
    vvn_receipt = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True,blank=True)
    vvn_fees = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True,)
    vvn_date = models.DateField(default=None,null=True,blank=True)
    claimed_date = models.DateField(default=None,blank=True,null=True)
    tot_claim_fees = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True,blank=True)
```

This is my model. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post the complete traceback. Your error is probably unrelated to NULL / NOT NULL.

Comment: exp = Edu_Expense(edu_receipt = edu_receipt, edu_fees = edu_fees, edu_date = edu_date, entry_receipt = entry_receipt, entry_fees = entry_fees, entry_date = entry_date, lab_receipt = lab_receipt, lab_fees = lab_fees, lab_date = lab_date, other_receipt = other_receipt, other_fees = other_fees, other_date = other_date, prac_receipt = prac_receipt, prac_fees = prac_fees, prac_date =prac_date, instru_receipt = instru_receipt, instru_fees = instru_fees, instru_date = instru_date, lib_receipt = lib_receipt, lib_fees =  lib_fees, lib_date = lib_date, sport_receipt = sport_receipt

Comment: I'm thinking of this: The Model has an 'ID' field added by Django automatically, and that ID field *can't* be null, at least if you've not specified an alternative field to use for unique indexing.

Comment: but its important for us to maintain foreign key constraint

Comment: its problem in datefield,how to allow null there?

Answer (score 0):

You can replicate this error in the python console by inputting:

```
int('')
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

So with this new found knowledge we can diagnose further your issue.

I am guessing you are using a model form (maybe with validation) in your application, this will mean that when you submit your form django is passing through an empty string `''`. At this point the value of the `IntegerField` is not being defined as `null/None` and instead `''` is being passed to your model which cannot cast this into an integer.

Hence you are seeing the error message:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

If you show your code surrounding the form we might be able to help further.